# Inserting into hash table

Tags: c, hash

I am trying to insert an integer into a hash table. To do this, I'm creating an array of node*'s and I'm trying to make assignments like `listarray[i]->data=5` possible. However, I'm still very confused with pointers and I'm crashing at the line with the comment '//crashes here' and I don't understand why. Was my initialization in main() invalid?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct node
      {
      int data;
      struct node * next;
      } node;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void insert (node **listarray, int size)
     {

     node *temp;
     int value = 11; //just some random value for now, eventually will be scanned in
     int index = value % size; // 11 modulo 8 yields 3

     printf ("index is %d\n", index); //prints 3 fine

     if (listarray[index] == NULL)
       {
       printf("listarray[%d] is NULL",index); //prints because of loop in main
       listarray[index]->data = value; //crashes here
       printf("listarray[%d] is now %d",index,listarray[index]->data); //never prints
       listarray[index]->next = NULL;
       }

     else
       {
       temp->next = listarray[index];
       listarray[index] = temp;
       listarray[index]->data = value;
       }
     }//end insert()



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int main()
      {
    int size = 8,i; //set default to 8

     node * head=NULL; //head of the list
     node **listarray = malloc (sizeof (node*) * size); //declare an array of Node *
                                          //do i need double pointers here?

          for (i = 0; i < size; i++)    //malloc each array position
          {
            listarray[i] = malloc (sizeof (node) * size);
            listarray[i] = NULL; //satisfies the first condition in insert();
          }

          insert(*&listarray,size);
      }
```

output:

```
    index is 3
    listarray[3] is NULL
```

(crash)

desired output:

```
index is 3
listarray[3] is NULL
listarray[3] is now 11
```

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted? It's an issue I'm confused on, and I gave reasoning for what I wrote instead of pasting it all with no explanation.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe the downvote is because you did some hair-raising things in your code. For example: You do `listarray[i] = malloc...` and in the next line you do `listarray[i] = NULL`. This doesn't make any sense at all...

Comment: Another good one is: You check whether `listarray[index] == NULL` and if so then you access `listarray[index]->data` anyway...

Comment: Pardon my inexperience, but I have comments explaining why I do that. I'm asking for some assistance on a site that assists new programmers. Perhaps an alternative solution?

Comment: Please read the answer by @MOehm. He explains on the issues I mentioned in more detail. Please follow his advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various issues here:

If you have a hash table of a certain `size`, then the hash code must map to a value between `0` and `size - 1`. Your default size is 8, but your hash code is `x % 13`, which means that your index might be out of bounds.

Your `insert` function should also pass the item to insert (unless that's the parameter called `size`, in which case it is severely misnamed).

```
 if (listarray[index] == NULL) {
     listarray[index]->data = value; //crashes here
     listarray[index]->next = NULL;
 }
```

It's no wonder that it crashes: When the node is `NULL`, you cannot dereference it with either `*` or `->`. You should allocate new memory here.

And you shouldn't allocate memory here:

```
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)    //malloc each array position
      {
        listarray[i] = malloc (sizeof (node) * size);
        listarray[i] = NULL; //satisfies the first condition in insert();
      }
```

Allocating memory and then resetting it to `NULL` is nonsense. `NULL` is a special value that means that no memory is at the pointed-to location. Just set all nodes to `NULL`, which means that the hash table starts out without any nodes. Allocate when you need a node at a certain position.

In the `else` clause, you write:

```
 else
   {
   temp->next = listarray[index];
   listarray[index] = temp;
   listarray[index]->data = value;
   }
```

but `temp` hasn't been allocated, but you dereference it. That's just as bad as dereferencing ´NULL`.

Your hash table also needs a means to handle collisions. It looks as if at every index in the hash table, there is a linked list. That's a good way to deal with it, but you haven't implemented it properly.

You seem to have problems to understand pointers. Perhaps you should start with a simpler data structure like a linked list, just to practice? When you have gotten a firm grasp of that, you can use what you've learned to implement your hash table.